# Zurb classes not working even after installing foundation-sites and settig up the app

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, zurb-foundation

I installed foundation-sites and jquery using npm, because I want to implement Zurb into my React app. But the class names do nothing to the web and they don't seem to be working. I tried adding Zurb using link tag, then in App.js using `import foundation.css` and then using this

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'foundation-sites';

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    $(document).foundation();
  }
}
```

but that does nothing either. How do I implement Zurb into my app?

Comment: Are the CSS files correctly loaded?

Comment: @DanielRuf I downloaded them from the official website, then put them in the Style folder of the App.